# how to add strikethrough on text using apache POI for word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am unable to find references for adding a strikethrough on a text using Apache POI for word.

I am trying to build a word document where I need to strike some of the keywords based on a logic. Hence, the keywords that I strike should looking something like this,

<s>keyword striked</s>

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_font_style.htm); it looks like all you need to do is use the `setStrikeThrough()` method on an `XWPFRun` object and set it to true like this:

```
XWPFRun textRun = paragraph.createRun();
textRun.setStrikeThrough(true);
```

**EDIT**

The `setStrike()` method has been deprecated. The new method is `setStrikeThrough()`. [Here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setStrikeThrough-boolean-) is a link to the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful. I would like to add a note. I noticed that .setStrike(boolean value) method has been deprecated. I found that we can use .setStrikeThrough(boolean value) instead. Please update your answer accordingly so it is helpful for future visitors. Ref: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setStrikeThrough-boolean-

Comment: @SaAn - Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer so your question no longer appears unanswered by the way.